# is PHP OOPs following Procedural Programming Appraoch

Tags: java, php

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$t = new two ();
class Two extends One {
}
class One {
}
```

> Fatal error: Class 'two' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Dev_Learning/php/OO/01_class/04_extendsTest.php on line 4

**Java**

```
public class ClassDefTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Two t = new Two();
}
}

class Two extends One {
}

class One { 
}
```

Comment: No, OOP ___isn't___ procedural, that's the whole point

Comment: Note that `two` !== `Two`, but define your classes before trying to instantiate them

Comment: You'll need to define the class before you can instantiate it as a variable, ie. $t = new two();

Comment: i know the difference between OOP VS Procedural approach, my question is PHP OOP...

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are getting is because you instantiate the object before the actual creation of the class

a PHP script is running from top down, so the compiler/interpreter first tries to instantiate an object of a class that is not yet defined.

```
<?php

class Two extends One {
}
class One {
}

$t = new Two ();
```

in your case, the example above will work. **[HERE](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/)** you can find a tutorial for beginners on PHP OOP.

**ALSO:** PHP is not actually case sensitive, with the exception of some cases, but a good practice is to keep your code "clean" and easy to read for someone that has a first glance of a PHP code. So if a newbie looks at it, (s)he should understand it. I suggest you do it like above, with `new Two()` having 't' in uppercase.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: yes you are correct, finally i understood that php is interpreted language, so php is not supporting late binding

Comment: nope it does not... PHP is not your avarage language as C, C# or Java... it is a scripting language interpreted by the server and outputted as HTML code. It executes from top to bottom sequentially, each line at a time.

Comment: P.S: if this is the answer that you are looking for, please accept it so other users can take advantage of it and the question can be marked as solved. Thank you! For any further questions, please do not hesitate to contact me :)

Comment: Java Code is also interpreted from top to bottom after code compilation, i concluded that lot of Object Oriented features are need to implement in PHP

Comment: I never said that Java, or any other programming language is not interpreted from top to bottom, actually they kind of all are. The difference is that PHP is not compiled, it's interpreted. BIG difference :)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, your two examples are not equivalent. Following your Java example, I'd rewrite it that way:

```
<?php
    class SomethingBetter {
        public static function main() {
            $t = new Two();
            echo "Kinda OK";
        }
    }

    class Two extends One {}
    class One {}

    $test = SomethingBetter::main(); // echoes Kinda OK
```

Comment: there is no constructor in my java code, why did you added a new constructor in php code.  main() method initiated by the JRE and constructor is instantiated while creating the object

Comment: OK, I changed it. That was just an illustration that in your examples aren't equivalent and if you rewrite it in the same fashion, you'll get the same results. You can't create an instance of an undefined class in Java as well.